# Is it possible to know no LE bluetooth TX signal strength?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I would like to know if is it possible to get programmatically the power value of TX bluetooth signal in android. I transmit something, I can read the RSSI in the remote device and send it back, but I don't know the TX power and I can't calculate attenuation of RF path (free space propagation model). I know that the signal can propagate in many ways, but I need just approximate value.
Thanks for all for any informations!
Peter.

Answer (score 0):

You can only know the TX power through the interface of your BLE device. If it is an iBeacon for example, then there is an interface for setting the desired TX power (tradeoff between radius and battery life). For example in the Estimote Beacons there is a configurable range between -30dBm and -4dBm (there is also API for retrieving this info). If your device is not configurable then you should advice the manufacturer's notes for this specific device which may reveals the TX power, probably in dBm.